# Избыточность сочетания "изучение учебного курса"

Tags: морфология

*Изучение учебного курса "..."* - неизбыточно ли сочетание?

Comment: Я знаю, старый вопрос и всё такое, но не могу пройти мимо.  "Не избыточно" пишется всё-таки раздельно, по-моему.

Answer (score 1):

Формально, вроде бы, нет. "Учить" и "учеба" в современном языке это чуть ли не разные корни, да и по смыслу здесь не одно и то же. Курс может быть подготовительный, скажем, или ещё какой.

Но на всякий случай посмотрите, можно ли по контексту убрать слово "учебный" вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Может, убрать не учебный, а изучение?
Например, "прохождение учебного курса"? М?